# Is there an eBook reader compatible Tripitaka?

Tags: tipitaka, canon

I would like to know if there exist a PDF version of Tripitaka which is compatible with an eBook reader(Kindle, Kobo alike)?

Comment: Thankyou, At the moment I am looking for Bhikkhu Bodhi's Samannaphala Sutta Commentary

Comment: I found [this PDF](http://www.bps.lk/olib/mi/mi019-p.html) which is his translation but without the commentary. It is "Extracted from *The Fruits of Recluseship: The Samaññaphala Sutta and its Commentaries*" -- which (as far as I can tell from Google) is a paperback available from Amazon or maybe [from here](http://www.bps.lk/cover.php?id=bp212s) (but I don't see evidence that it's published as an eBook).

Comment: I hesitate to suggest this because some people don't agree with everything he writes, but if I want a commentary then the first place I think of looking is http://dharmafarer.org/wordpress/sutta-titles-2 ... there, many suttas are translated with an introduction and footnotes and cross-references, each in its own PDF, for example [here is the one for the Samannaphala Sutta](http://dharmafarer.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/8.10-Samannaphala-S-d2-piya.pdf).

Answer (score 7):

I am presuming you are looking for translations. There is the Buddha Jayanthi edition which has both Sinhala and Pali.

English

- http://dharmafarer.org/ - does not have all the Tripitaka but there is a growing number of Suttas in PDF form
- http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ - this has traslation by many and can be downladed in multiple formats in mulitple languages

Multi languages

- https://suttacentral.net/ - no PDF but mobile friendly. But has translations in multiple languages

Pali

- http://www.tipitaka.org/ - Pali text is many different scripts with PDF downloads

Sinhala (Since you name sounds like a Sinhalese name including including some in Singhala script)

- http://www.aathaapi.org/Thripitaka.html - Buddha Jayanthi in PDF
- http://metta.lk/tipitaka/, http://pitaka.lk/ -  A.P. de Soyza's translations (https://www.facebook.com/pitaka.lk has links to PDFs)
- http://www.thripitakaya.org/ - Unicode mobile friendly format.

Answer (score 3):

As well as the suttas which are listed in [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/14240/254):

- There are translations from the Vinaya [linked here](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/vin/) on Access to Insight (many of the PDFs are commentaries rather than translations).
- [This page](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/abhi/) (from 2005) of Access to Insight implies (though I don't know if that's true) that many of the Abhidhamma books haven't even been translated at all, let alone made available in eBook format. Still, there is at least [A Manual of Abhidhamma](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/abhidhamma.pdf), a commentary in PDF format. There are also [translations of the Visuddhimagga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visuddhimagga#English_translations) (not sure whether that counts as tipitaka).
- Also:

  - There are many PDFs at http://static.sirimangalo.org/pdf/ including suttas, Pali grammars, texts from the vinaya, dhammapada, jataka, etc.
  - There's an eBook library at http://www.buddhistelibrary.org/en/index.php?lang=english (which may have some books not found elsewhere, in its [Theravada Texts](http://www.buddhistelibrary.org/en/index.php?cat=7) category).
  - These [Pali Text Society Publications](http://obo.genaud.net/backmatter/indexes/idx_downloads.htm#pts_pdfs) are suttas in PDF format (actually they're ZIP files with a PDF inside, I don't know whether you can unzip on the Kindle, or need to download and then unzip before copying to Kindle).

Answer (score 2):

You can find here some selected sutta translations from the Pali Canon, as translated by Thanissaro Bhikku to English, in the azw3, mobi, epub and pdf formats. With Kindle, please use the mobi format for best results.

http://www.dhammatalks.org/ebook_index.html

Here's what you can find at this page:

- Handful of Leaves: an Anthology from the Sutta Pitaka, translated by Thanissaro Bhikkhu (revised Jan. 21, 2016)
- Handful of Leaves, Volume I: an Anthology from the Digha Nikaya, translated by Thanissaro Bhikkhu. (revised Jan. 17, 2016)
- Handful of Leaves, Volume II: an Anthology from the Majjhima Nikaya, translated by Thanissaro Bhikkhu. (revised Dec. 31, 2015)
- Handful of Leaves, Volume III: an Anthology from the Samyutta Nikaya, translated by Thanissaro Bhikkhu. (revised Dec. 31, 2015)
- Handful of Leaves, Volume IV: an Anthology from the Anguttara Nikaya, translated by Thanissaro Bhikkhu. (revised Jan. 19, 2016)
- Itivuttaka: This was said by the Buddha, translated by Thanissaro Bhikkhu. (revised Jan. 21, 2015)
- Udana: Exclamations, translated by Thanissaro Bhikkhu. (revised Jan. 21, 2015)
- Dhammapada: A Translation, translated by Thanissaro Bhikkhu. (revised Dec. 10, 2014; pdf revised Dec 16, 2015)
- Poems of the Elders: An Anthology from the Theragatha & Therigatha, translated by Thanissaro Bhikkhu. (revised Jan. 19, 2016)
- The Buddhist Monastic Code, Volumes I & II, translated and explained by Thanissaro Bhikkhu. (revised Jan. 10, 2014)

Answer (score 2):

The Full set of the scans of the PTS translations of the 4 Nikāyas and the Vinaya are available in zipped PDF files at:
http://buddhadust.net/backmatter/indexes/idx_downloads.htm#pts_pdfs

This is the same collection as mentioned above as located at obo.genaud.net. That site has become obsolete due to our inability to update the site and has been replaced by buddhadust.net. This site also has the full set of PTS translations in html format. The new site has been completely converted to Unicode which makes use of the source files much easier.

If these files are wanted strictly for personal reading, the PDFs will just make it: they are not of the best quality scans. They were originally put together to assist in proofreading the html files. If what is wanted is a clear rendering for further distribution it would probably be better to take the source files of the html version and convert them directly with a tool like Calibre.

The site also contains all the Bhk. Bodhi translations made available to the public gratis; the translations of Bhk. Thanissaro; the Sister Upalavanna translations, the translations of the Majjhima of Lord Chalmers, the manuscript of Bhk. Nanamoli's translation of the Majjhima, and the individual sutta translations of a variety of lesser-known translators and the Pali text. All in html format. Translations are linked to each other and to the Pali. See the Sutta Index Page:
http://buddhadust.net/backmatter/indexes/sutta/sutta_toc.htm
which lists every single sutta with a short description. The PTS suttas have also mostly been unabridged in the html version.