# Help for a monks studies

Tags: monk, tipitaka

I am an Australian monk at Pa Auk Tawya in Myanmar. For my studies I need some tipitaka translations to read on my kindle (available from amazon).
I have no means to pay for these. Any suggestions?

With metta

Comment: Bhante, there's a partial answer here: [Is there an eBook reader compatible Tripitaka?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/14236/254)